# Why is wrapping figures around text such a hard problem?

Tags: wrapfigure, wrap, insbox

I'm writing a document where I wanted to wrap a list around a text box, and I eventually got the following result:

[image]

I had to search on the internet for hours before I found a way to wrap a list around a box. Wrapfig doesn't work with lists apparently. Insbox doesn't either, unless you do some modifications. This is the code I ended up with:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\input{insbox}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{parskip}

\newcommand*{\wrapitem}{\apptocmd{\labelitemi}{\hskip\leftmargin}{}{}\item\apptocmd{\labelitemi}{\hskip-\leftmargin}{}{}}
\newcommand{\InsertListR}[3][]{%
\mbox{}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\setlength{\leftskip}{\leftmargin}%
\InsertBoxR{#2}{\hskip-\leftmargin#3\hskip\leftmargin}[#1]%
}%

\begin{document}
Un par de cosas importantes:
\begin{itemize}
    \wrapitem%
    \InsertListR{1}{\tcbox[title=Recuerda,tikznode={align=left}]{%
Una ecuación\\ forma parte de una oración\\así que no te olvides\\de usar la puntuación.}}\vspace{0.4ex}%
Las ecuaciones normalmente \textbf{no} son un nuevo párrafo. No cojas costumbre de añadir líneas en blanco antes y después de las ecuaciones en el código, porque introduce demasiado espacio.
\end{itemize}
%
\begin{itemize}
    \wrapitem%
    \InsertListR[-6]{0}{\phantom{\tcbox[title=Recuerda,tikznode={align=left}]{%
Una ecuación\\ forma parte de una oración\\así que no te olvides\\de usar la puntuación.}}}%
Las ecuaciones son parte de una oración. Al final de ellas, por tanto, suele haber una coma o un punto, igual que en cualquier otra  oración.
    \item Evita introducir todas tus ecuaciones con dos puntos, queda muy mal.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

It's held together by duct tape, and gives a bunch of warnings about overfull hboxes. I even had to make a phantom version of the box to ensure the second item would have the same distance to the right margin, and then manually correct the amount of lines that phantom box has to cover.

Using LibreOffice Writer (essentially a free version of MS Word), it took me 5 minutes to make this:

[image]

Now of course, the box doesn't look as nice, but come on. I can literally drag the text box, place it anywhere I want, and the program dynamically adjusts the text around it.

And this isn't just about lists; it's in general pretty hard to get good results when wrapping text around images or text boxes with LaTeX. I guess I just want to understand why is it that this seemingly trivial task for many text editors, is so hard to do seamlessly in LaTeX. Or maybe I'm just missing something and there's a super simple way to achieve that result that I haven't found yet?

Comment: (a) What is the file size (bytes) of all binaries (including bin/exe and lib/dll) the come with LibreOffice? (b) What is the file size for Tex? Compare. Remember that the TeX *.sty files are usually plain text scripts, not binaries that can dynamically respond to real-time user activity.

Comment: lists change the \parshape, and \wrapfig changes the \parshape and that clashes.

Comment: @rallg I understand that TeX isn't going to do this dynamically, but why is it so hard to have a command that just puts a box in a specific place, and then automatically wraps all the text around it?

Comment: First, LaTeX is paragrpah oriented.   Wrapping text is easy if you stick to paragraph boundaries, all you need is `\rightskip` or `\leftskip`.  Doing it part way through a paragraph is difficult.  You can always do it by breaking the paragraphs manually using something like `\nopar` or `\splitpar`.

Comment: In ConTeXt one can get that by adding hang to the float placement. In the [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EThUK.png) below I used the options`right,nonumber,hang,low` to the float. With `2*hang` the yellow frame would have been pushed one more line down.

Comment: Every tool is good at certain things and bad at others. In LaTeX it is, for example, easy to make nice boxes with `tcolorbox`, in LibreOffice this is harder. In LaTeX you have to struggle to customize the layout of the document, in LibreOffice this is easier (although it can still be very difficult to get a uniform, consistent, reproducible layout for the full document in LibreOffice). But the point is that for each situation you should choose the tool that makes it easy to perform the task that you want, instead of trying to force a tool to do something that it is not designed to do.